# Javascript / NodeJs different async functions resulting in one big json file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, asynchronous

I simply can't figure this out. I have a folder with files. I want to create a json with information of these files. To be precise the filename, a regexed version of the filename and additional data I get from a ajax call.

The individual parts work perfectly. In fact, if I run my code in sync, I will get the result I want. Something like this:

```
 [
          { 
              "filename" : "first file",
              "regexname" : "first file",
              "ajaxresult" : "first file"
          },
          { 
              "filename" : "second file",
              "regexname" : "second file",
              "ajaxresult" : "second file"
          },
 ]
```

But I want to do it async because the XHR module I use doesn't work properly when trying to do everything 'in sync' and it's of course blocking especially with a lot of files.
My 'in sync' code looks like this (a bit simplified to make it shorter )

```
  fs.readdir(datapath, function(err, files) { 
    var data = new Array();
        if(err) throw err;
        files.forEach(function(file){
            var filename = file
            , regex= filename.replace(/regex/)/i, "")
            , filepath = './public/config/dataconfig.js'
            , ajaxResults = getFile(url)
            , mapFiles = null

        mapFiles = { filename:filename, regexname:regex, ajaxcall:ajaxResults}
        data[data.length] = mapfiles;
    }
    var JSONdata= JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
    fs.writeFile(filepath, JSONdata, function(e) {
        if (!e) {
            console.log('Done')
        }else{ 
            console.log('Failed', e)   
        };
    });
 });
```

I tried wrapping the ajaxcall in a promise, but I lose the filename and regexname inside the promise. like so:

```
  fs.readdir(datapath, function(err, files) { 
    var data = new Array();
        if(err) throw err;
        files.forEach(function(file){
            var filename = file
            , regex= filename.replace(/regex/)/i, "")
            , filepath = './public/config/dataconfig.js'
            , mapFiles = null

        // Make promise for async call with a url composed of the regex
        var promise = getFile(url);
        promise.then( function(result) {
             mapFiles = { filename:filename, regexname:regex, ajaxcall:result}
             data[data.length] = mapfiles;
                 var JSONdata= JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
                 fs.writeFile(filepath, JSONdata, function(e) {
                    if (!e) {
                          console.log('Done')
                     }else{ 
                          console.log('Failed', e)   
                     };
                  });
            }); 
  });
```

This gives me the following result:

```
 [
          { 
              "filename" : "first file",
              "regexname" : "first file",
              "ajaxresult" : "first file"
          },
          { 
              "filename" : "first file",
              "regexname" : "first file",
              "ajaxresult" : "second file"
          },
 ]
```

So my final thought was to use something like the async module for node. writing the json after I get callbacks back from the function. but I can't get that to work either.

Thanks in advance!

**[EDIT - what I forgot to mention ]**

A thing I forgot to mention is that the AjaxCall url is built with the regex. 
So something like this:

```
      url = 'http://www.test.com/'+regex
```

So this (as I see it) would mean I do the regex before calling the ajaxcall but I also need the regex after the call to write in the Json. I hope this makes sence

**[EDIT 2 - A bit more information]**

My XHR call looks like this (without my faulty promise solution. In that case I return the promise with the result):

```
// Get info
function getFile(url) { 
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.open("GET", url); 
    xhr.onreadystatechange = handler
    var ajaxResult = null
    //Callback
    function handler (){
        // If status is ready
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            ajaxResult = eval(this.responseText);
            console.log('XHR OK')
        };
    };
    xhr.send(null);
    return ajaxResult[0];
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution based on promises, that will work properly, may look like:

```
readdir(datapath).map(function (file) {
  return getFile(url)(function (ajaxresult) {
    return writeFile('./public/config/dataconfig.js', JSON.stringifiy({
      filename: file,
      regexname: file.replace(/regex/i, ""),
      ajaxcall: ajaxResult
    }, null, 4));
  });
}).end(function () {
  console.log("All done");
}, function (e) {
  console.log("Failed", e);
});
```

In this example I used [deferred](https://github.com/medikoo/deferred) promise implementation, to make it work you need to make sure that all async functions return promises. Typical callback functions can be converted easily with deferred.promisify:

```
var promisify = require('deferred').promisify;
var readdir = promisify(fs.readdir);
var writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I guess I just don't see it but this gives me a 'Failed [TypeError: Caonnot read property '0' of null]. But I don't get where it comes from. The XHR call gives me the correct data once (which is what makes it weird for me).

Comment: Vpml can you show full error stack trace or code exactly as you run it?

Comment: Error is caused by getFile, which is supposed to return promise, but instead it tries to get index from null property (hence "Cannot read property '0' of null"). Following should work: http://jsfiddle.net/medikoo/BvQkJ/4/

Comment: I hate to be asking so much of your time. Thanks for all the help so far, but sadly. I get the following error: Failed [TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'stringifiy']. But I don't understand why I get this error because neither file, movieTitle and scraperresults seem to cause the error nor the added deferred. I simple don't see the cause. Again thanks!

Comment: Vprnl, error message is a best hint, there's a typo, should be 'stringify' instead of 'stringifyi' ;-)

Comment: Haha Thanks so much! I knew it was something stupid! My god I feel in debt to you now, but the resulting Json only has one result. Instead of three (the amount of test files i have lined up)

Comment: Yes, the way it is currently setup, it writes JSON for each file individually, but if you do that: http://jsfiddle.net/medikoo/BvQkJ/6/
then array of files data will be saved to one config file

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a quick example using [async](http://github.com/caolan/async), as you mentioned:

```
doStuffWithFiles('folder', 'output.json', function () {
  console.log('Done!');
});

function doStuffWithFiles (dirPath, outputFilePath, callback) {
  fs.readdir(dirPath, function (error, files) {
    async.map(
      files,
      function (file, callback) {
        doAjaxStuff(file, function (error, ajaxResults) {
          callback(null, {
            filename:    file,
            regexStuff:  file.replace(/stuff/, ''),
            ajaxResults: ajaxResults
          });
        });
      },
      function (error, results) {
        var data = JSON.stringify(results);
        fs.writeFile(outputFilePath, data, function (error) {
          callback();
        });
      }
    );
  });
}
```

The key part is `async.map` which acts like the [standard `map` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) except it requires you to return your results as arguments to the callback passed to your first function. Once all the callbacks have returned, `async.map` calls the second function, passing it the list of results.

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer. This is almost exactly what I need. Only one thing I forgot to mention though; the 'doAjaxStuff' uses the 'regexStuff' in the url. so for example something like this: url = 'http://www.test.com/'+regexStuff. 

The doAjaxStuff function will look like this: getInfo(url, function (error, result)){

I rather not repeat the regex twice of course. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is getting the filename and regex, how about binding them to your callback
like

```
var callback = function(result) {
         mapFiles = { filename:this.filename, regexname:this.regex, ajaxcall:result}
         data[data.length] = mapfiles;
             var JSONdata= JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
             fs.writeFile(filepath, JSONdata, function(e) {
                if (!e) {
                 console.log('Done')
                 }else{ 
                  console.log('Failed', e)   
                 };
              }
```

then

```
promise.then(callback.bind({'filename':filename,'regex':regex}))
```

Comment: what do you need to use promises in node.js?

Comment: honestly i have no idea, never used it